# Can one save a pandas DataFrame to binary in "append mode"?

Tags: python, pandas

Can one save a pandas DataFrame to binary in "append" mode, analogous to using mode='a' in the to_csv() DataFrame method? It would be nice to have:

```
df.save( path = 'myFrame', mode = 'a' )
```

Based on the suggestion below I've gone with

```
def pdAppendPickle( data, path ):
""" Intent: append pickle containing dataframe """
    with open( path, 'a' ) as f:
        pkl.dump( data, f )
```

It is a shame, however, that this isn't interoperable with pd.load( ) and isn't the same as pd.save() because we are not concatenating. One has to use something like:

```
def pdLoadPickles( path ):
    """ Load one or more pickles containing dataframes and concatenate  """
    f   = open( path, 'r' )
    dfs = list()
    while True:
       try:
          df = pkl.load( f )
          dfs.append( df )
       except:
          break     
    f.close()        
    return pd.concat( dfs, axis = 0 )
```

If anyone has an elegant solution which is truly the incremental version of pd.save() I'd still like to see it.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by just using `pickle`/`cPickle` directly:

```
In [78]: import cPickle as pkl

In [79]: df = DataFrame(randint(5, size=(5, 2)))

In [80]: df
Out[80]:
   0  1
0  3  2
1  4  1
2  0  3
3  0  0
4  4  1

In [81]: df2 = DataFrame(randint(5, size=(5, 2)))

In [82]: df2
Out[82]:
   0  1
0  2  1
1  1  0
2  1  0
3  0  0
4  1  3

In [83]: with open('appended.pkl', 'a') as f:
   ....:     pkl.dump(df, f)
   ....:

In [84]: with open('appended.pkl', 'a') as f:
   ....:     pkl.dump(df2, f)
   ....:

In [85]: f = open('appended.pkl', 'r')

In [86]: pkl.lo
pkl.load   pkl.loads

In [86]: pkl.load(f)
Out[86]:
   0  1
0  3  2
1  4  1
2  0  3
3  0  0
4  4  1

In [87]: pkl.load(f)
Out[87]:
   0  1
0  2  1
1  1  0
2  1  0
3  0  0
4  1  3
```

Comment: Thanks. Ideally pd.load('appended.pkl') would retrieve the concatenated dataframe.

Comment: PRs/suggestions are very welcome over on pandas github. They won't necessarily be accepted but would be ok to discuss